I am having trouble placing arrowheads on 2D vectors using python pyplot and keeping the rest of my cartesian grid as is
I am plotting 2D vectors in a Cartesian grid using matplotlib pyplot and I would like to have arrowheads on them. This is the plot I have achieved so far:

I want grid lines spaced every 1 unit and I want the grid to be "square" meaning x-axis and y-axis should go from -a to +a where "a" will depend on the longest vector. I've achieved that. I tried pyplot.quiver (plt.quiver) but then the other features, just mentioned, are gone. Her is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M = np.array([[1,5],[-2,2],[4,-5]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rows,cols = M.T.shape
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))


maxes = np.amax(abs(M), axis = 0)
lim = np.amax(abs(maxes), axis = 0) +1


for i,l in enumerate(range(0,cols)):
    xs = [0,M[i,0]]
    ys = [0,M[i,1]]
    plt.plot(xs,ys)

list = []                            
for i in range(-lim,lim+1):
    list.append(i)
   
plt.xticks(list) 
plt.yticks(list)

plt.plot(0,0,'ok')                      
plt.axhline(0,linewidth = 1, color="black")
plt.axvline(0,linewidth = 1, color="black")

plt.xlim([-lim,lim])          
plt.ylim([-lim,lim])          
plt.legend(['V'+str(i+1) for i in range(cols)])
plt.grid(which='both')
plt.show()

Thanks in advance.

I found what I need.
'''
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x=np.array([-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y=np.array([-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,10], dpi = 120)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.plot(x,y,linewidth = 1, alpha=0.0)

plt.arrow(0, 0, 2, 5, color="blue", linewidth = 2, head_width = 0.3,    length_includes_head = True)
plt.arrow(2, 5, -3, 3, color="blue", linewidth = 2, head_width = 0.3, length_includes_head = True)
plt.arrow(0, 0, -1, 8, color="red", linewidth = 2, head_width = 0.3, length_includes_head = True)

plt.grid(True,"both","both", color="black",linewidth = 2)
plt.show()

'''
I had to plot a set of (x,y) ordered pairs and make the plot completely transparent (alpha = 0.0) in order to achieve the proper grid aspect. I think there is probably a more pythonic way to do this but this works for me. The key was pyplot.arrow.

